# what can be the numebr in super_block.s_log_block_size is it always 0 for ext2 filesystem does why It depends on block size?

Tags: c, filesystems, ext2

So If block size can be found in ext2 like

```
 block_size = 1024 << super_block.s_log_block_size;
```

so I like to know what is s_log_block_size field. it looks like value can be 0 and should always be 0 in ext2 formatted device as in ext2 block size is 1024 so and hardcoding it in code  like 1024 `block_size=1024<<super_block->s_log_block_size`

so I like to know what is `super_block.s_log_block_size` can it always be case. In one image formatted with  ext2 that I have on my system its super_block.s_log_block_size value is 0 and its normally zero. So I like to know what is the point of this le32 bit field?

Comment: If the filesystem have a block-size of `1024` bytes, then `s_log_block_size` will be zero. But filesystems can have other block-sizes. For example if the block-size is `4096` then `s_log_block_size` will be `2`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please do tell `For example if the block-size is 4096 ` is block size is 40i96 then its not ext2 file system in ext2 file system s_log_block_size should be zero if doing `block_size=(1024<<s_log_block_size)` or I could simply write block_size=1024. is this correct understanding?

Comment: Ext2 can have almost any block-size. There's no rule that says you must use `1024`. The main limitation is that the Linux kernel doesn't allow a block-size larger than the VM page size (4096 on x86 systems). You really need to find some more documentation to read.